# Exceeded Request quota for this API error

Tags: google-maps

We have already successfully configured the API Key but we keep getting the error error  See [You have exceeded your request quota for this API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/error-messages#billing-and-http-referer-errors). Do I need to enable the billing for this?

[This is the link that has error](https://accenturece.avature.net/eventsEN/EventDetail/Chicago-Illinois-United-States-FY20-Chicago-I-D-Super-Day-s/6240)

Comment: You need to pay in order to use it further.

Comment: Yes.  You need to enable billing (without billing enabled, your quota is ~1 query)

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking the [site](https://accenturece.avature.net/eventsEN/EventDetail/Chicago-Illinois-United-States-FY20-Chicago-I-D-Super-Day-s/6240), the error was related to having no billing account, to fix the issue, kindly create a billing account in your [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) and associate the billing account to your project where the API key you're currently using belongs. After associating a billing account, your map should be working fine.

In addition, please note that you can only call a single API request if you don't have a valid billing account associated to your project.